# MoonMail Source Code - AWS integration with serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, moonmail

I'm trying to configure the MoonMail source code on AWS by Serverless, but when following the steps on [github](https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail), it doesn’t work.

According to the information, an error occurred while provisioning the cloud formation:

> “ServerlessError: ServerlessError: An error occurred while
>   provisioning your cloudformation: The following resource(s) failed to
>   create: [AutomationsTable, AwsMarketplaceNotificationsQueue,
>   ScheduledEmailsTable, ListExportS3Bucket, PrecompileCampaignTopic,
>   SentEmailsTable, SendCampaignTopic, PrecompileEmailTopic,
>   AttachRecipientsTopic, ListSegmentsTable, CampaignsTable,
>   TemplatesTable, FreeUsersSendEmailQueue, AttachSegmentRecipientsTopic,
>   UsersTable, EventsBusTopic, IamRoleLambda, AttachListRecipientsTopic,
>   RecipientsTable, StaticDataBucket, AutomationActionsTable,
>   ClicksReportTable, PaymentLogsTable, LinksTable,
>   UpdateListImportStatusTopic, ExpertsTable, EmailAdminsTopic,
>   ClicksTable, ListsTable, UpdateCampaignTopic, SendEmailsTopic,
>   OpensTable, OpensReportTable, RecipientsImportS3Bucket, ReportsTable].
>   . Delete requested by user.”

On CloudFormation no stack is created. I already tried some suggestions that can be found online, mainly on stackOverflow trough the MoonMail tag, but none seemed to work.

Thanks.

Comment: which serverless version do you run with, the repo is set with old serverless version, which may not work well with latest.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am running into the same thing.